# Not able to understand Input decorator behaviour

Tags: angular

I am implementing Input and Output decorator and I got confused about a functionality. What is happening here?

Parent Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './template.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {

}
```

parent template

```
<h1>Parent</h1>
<app-child placeHolderTxt="Add User"></app-child>
<app-child placeHolderTxt="Add Admin"></app-child>
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './template.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() placeHolderTxt = "";
  count = 0;  
  addUser = function(){
    this.count += 1;    
  }
}
```

child template

```
<div style="float:left;margin-left:100px; border: 1px solid black">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{placeHolderTxt}}"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" (click)="addUser()" value="ADD"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Count : {{count}}</td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

When I am clicking in Add User Add button it increases count by 1 each time but the count for admin remains 0. My problem is that I am not able to understand why it's showing 0 count for admin as for display count. I am using same child component member.

Comment: `i am implementing Input and Output decorator`... I don't see anywhere use of `@Output`?

Comment: @AJT_82 i am in between of this got stucked in this and asked question

Comment: Sounds very unlikely. Can you create a stackblitz app ?

Comment: so you expect when you click add on either of the child components, it should increment in both child components? If so, that is not how it works, these are two separate components with two separate `count`.

Comment: @AJT_82 no i don't want this but i confused in this as count and addUser both are elements of Child component so why  increased count showing for user only why not for admin

Comment: Because these are two completely separate components. A simple example. Your sister wins 100$ from the lottery. Do you expect that you also win 100$ when she does? No, because you are two completely different people and you might not even have entered the lottery.

Comment: @user1234 so do you need other clarifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` field isn't shared between *Component* instances.

You have two `app-child` elements, and it means you'll have two independent `count`s.

```
<app-child placeHolderTxt="Add User" [count]="count" (increment)="onIncrement()"></app-child>
<app-child placeHolderTxt="Add Admin" [count]="count" (increment)="onIncrement()"></app-child>
```

---

You can leverage an `@Output` `EventEmitter`, and move up the `count` variable.

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() placeHolderTxt = "";
  @Input() count = 0;

  @Output() increment = new EventEmitter<void>(true);

  addUser(): void {
    this.increment.emit();
  }
}
```

---

```
export class ParentComponent {
  count = 0;

  onIncrement(): void {
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: but count is not attribute of Parent Component its a member of Child Component pls see my code i have added it in Child Component and same is shared in Child Component template that's why i am confusing why only user count is shown as increased

Comment: @user1234 you need to move it to the parent.

Comment: @user1234 its because you have 2 instances of ChildComponent Class, and count is limited to that instance.
If you want to update in both admin/user then either you have to derive count from parent component